# ADB from ADK ATmega Arduino board disconnects when power fail and resume

Tags: android

In my Android project based on **ATmega 2560 Arduino ADK board**.ADB connection is using for communication with Android Device. It is working fine ,but the problem is **after the power interruption (failure and resume)ADB is not automatically connecting** , for getting ADB connection I have to re-plug(remove & again plug)USB cable.This is not practical for my project.If anybody having idea pl guide me .

Thanks in advance.